# Fontawesome icon inside Reactstrap input group

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, reactstrap

I’m trying to place icons near input fields, and when I insert FontAwesomeIcon component inside InputGroupAddon component, it doesn’t look as it suppose to be. There is my [code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/9264j0770o). What I want to get:  [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTRzp.png). What I really get: [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6rkM.png).

Comment: Please put your code example as a part of the question (not as a link).

Comment: code example link no longer works - this question is almost useless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put FontAwesomeIcon component inside span tag

```
<span className="input-group-text"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} /></span>
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding `className="input-group-text"` to `<InputGroupAddon />` also works.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can use InputGroupText

```
<InputGroup>
    <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
        <InputGroupText>
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" aria-hidden="true" style={{color:'#675cff', fontSize: 18}}>
            </i>
        </InputGroupText>
    </InputGroupAddon>
    <Input Style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', color:'Black'}} placeholder="Enter Name">
    </Input>
</InputGroup>
```